# nuance omnipage OCR SDK Engine.SetLicenseKey()

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, распознавание-символов

Я использую nuance omnipage OCR SDK для распознавания текста в PDF файлах.

Когда скомпилировал проект, получил ошибку во время исполнения Engine initialization error, or no appropriate license.
Судя по всему не указана лицензия для либы. И я нашел метод Engine.SetLicenseKey(), чтобы это исправить, но вот параметры его не совсем понятны.
Параметрами являются 2 строки: файл и ключ.

Исследую многочисленную документацию, ничего об этом не выявил, также в демо проектах это не разбирается.

Где взять эти файл, ключ и инструкцию?

UPD:добавил код:

```
try
{
    List<OCR_Error> ocrErrors = new List<OCR_Error>();
    System.Console.Write("** Title: Nuance Capture Development System CSharp Sample01 Application **\n");
    System.Console.Write("Initializing the ENGine -- Engine.Init\n");
    Engine.SetLicenseKey("licenseFile.lcx", "licenseKey");
    Engine.Init("companyName", "projectName");
    if (Engine.RECERR == RECERR.API_INIT_WARN)
    {
        ocrErrors.Add(new OCR_Error()
        {
            Message = "Module initialization warning. One or more recognition modules haven't been initialized properly.",
            InnerMessage = "For more information, see Engine.ModulesInfo"
        });
        return;
    }
    string inputFileName = @"D:\3141864.pdf";
    string inputFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(inputFileName);
    string outputFilePath = inputFilePath.Replace('.', '_') + @".pdf";
    if (File.Exists(outputFilePath))
        File.Delete(outputFilePath);
    File.Create(outputFilePath);

    using (SettingCollection settings = new SettingCollection())
    {
        using (Document doc = new Document(inputFilePath))
        {
            int sourcePagesCount = doc.PageCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < sourcePagesCount; i++)
            {
                using (Page page = new Page(inputFilePath, i, settings))
                {
                    page.Preprocess();
                    page.Recognize();
                    using (Document oputputDocument = new Document(outputFilePath, 0, settings))
                    {
                        oputputDocument.InsertPage(page, i);
                        oputputDocument.Save(outputFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Console.Write(e.Message);//Ощибка: License Manager error.
}
finally
{
    System.Console.Write("Free all resources allocated by the Engine -- Engine.ForceQuit\n");
    Engine.ForceQuit();
    System.Console.Write("End of Sample01 application\n");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: по русски пожалуйста

Comment: @Dmitry, простите, думал английский Stack Overflow, сейчас переведу

Comment: @Dmitry, перевод готов

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, перевел

Comment: @Nemo, в техподдержку вопрос задавали?

Comment: @Dmitry, вот в том и проблема, что на их форумах пусто, и практически все вопросы без ответов остаются..

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что обращаться следует в техподдержку продавца библиотеки/программы.

Comment: @Nemo, а что поди еще и либа купленная? Нагибайте ТП, если купили, потом нам расскажите :)

Comment: @Dmitry, ну пока еще нет, триалку заказали

Comment: @Nemo, сигнатуру как она есть скинте сюда, а точнее в вопрос добавьте. и опишите, что уже пробовали, что не получилось, какие исключения увидали

Comment: @Dmitry, код добавил

Comment: @Nemo, а сигнатура то какая? string & string?

Comment: @Dmitry, 1)конструктор: 2 параметра string filename, string key;
2)конструктор: 3 параметра string filename, string version, string key;

Comment: @Nemo почту проверяли на наличие всего этого хозяйства? ну или личный кабинет?

Comment: @Dmitry, они в SDK выслали кучу документации, но практически ничего не было описанно по использованию, в примерах данный вопрос не разбирался.

Comment: @Nemo, ну так я не про это спрашивал, я про файлы и ключ. вполне возможно, что их и нет, но для этого должен быть пустой конструктор, он есть?

Comment: @Dmitry, пустого нету, после установки была тулза, для активации лицензии, но она файлов не генерировала, я скачал с личного кабинета файл .lcx, положил вместе с исполняемым файлом и передал в качестве имени файла, а в качестве ключа - ключ активации, в итоге полчил ошибку - "License Manager error."

Comment: @Nemo, ммм, ну тогда вам стоит терзать ТП, вопрос по их части.